# Grafana will not restart after update from 3.1 to 4.3

Tags: grafana

On centos 7 we ran `yum update grafana` and updated from 3.1 to 4.3. After the update grafana will not start.

```
systemctl status grafana-server
● grafana-server.service - Grafana instance
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2017-05-23 19:59:03 PDT; 2s ago
Docs: http://docs.grafana.org
Process: 1704 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/grafana-server --config=${CONF_FILE} --pidfile=${PID_FILE} cfg:default.paths.logs=${LOG_DIR} cfg:default.paths.data=${DATA_DIR} cfg:default.paths.plugins=${PLUGINS_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 1704 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 23 19:59:02 test1 systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: main process exited, ...URE
May 23 19:59:02 test1 systemd[1]: Unit grafana-server.service entered failed state.
May 23 19:59:02 test1 systemd[1]: grafana-server.service failed.
May 23 19:59:03 test1 systemd[1]: grafana-server.service holdoff time over, sch...rt.
May 23 19:59:03 test1 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for grafan...ice
May 23 19:59:03 test1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Grafana instance.
May 23 19:59:03 test1 systemd[1]: Unit grafana-server.service entered failed state.
May 23 19:59:03 test1 systemd[1]: grafana-server.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Is there a step we need to do to get grafana to run again?, thanks in advance

Comment: It would be useful if you included the output from `journalctl -u grafana-server.service` (there's likely to be something a bit earlier than the first log line in the output). Also, adding `-l` to the `systemctl` invocation would make it not truncate lines.

Comment: What port is your Grafana running on?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the config files in /etc/grafana/ disappeared after the update to 4.3. Simply workaround is to cp them before the update and mv them back afterwards.